# Particular values of the Riemann zeta function.

Tags: special-functions, riemann-zeta, bernoulli-numbers

On the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Specific_values), near the bottom of the "Specific Values" section, there is a statement that bothers me.

> $$\zeta(-13)=\zeta(-1)$$

Firstly, it is well noted that the summations must be evaluated somehow, despite the fact that they are divergent.

Secondly, it just seemed very random, without much reinforcement, so I feel as though it could be a typo or foul play.

Hopefully the latter is false and someone can shed some light on proving they are equal.

Comment: You do know that $\zeta(s)$ has a reflection formula, no?

Comment: @J.M. Oh, that makes much more sense.  Sorry for the trivial question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out to be an identity about [Bernoulli numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliNumber.html), $B_2=B_{14}-1$. They both are rational numbers, and their denominators have to be the same by the [Von Staudt-Clausen theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Staudt%E2%80%93Clausen_theorem). Equality of numerators, too, happens more or less by chance.